# How to change line color automatically in rxgraph?

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because when rxgraph show many lines on the screen,sometimes it's difficult to each line of goal.

If it is possible to change color automatically,it will be easy to understand.

The normal black line:

[image: image description]

I use grep to find color,but what I found is not black:

```
 sam@/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/rx/rxgraph/src/rxgraph$ grep color *
 dotcode.py:            return '  %s [color="red", shape="doublecircle",      label="%s", URL="node:%s"];'%(
 dotcode.py:            return '  %s [color="orange", shape="doublecircle",      label="%s", URL="node:%s"];'%(
 二進位格式檔案 dotcode.pyc 符合
 
 sam@/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/rx/rxgraph/src/rxgraph$
```

Where is the setting of line of color?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10689/how-to-change-line-color-automatically-in-rxgraph?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently there is no way to change the color of the lines in rxgraph programatically. But you could add that feature to rxgraph and patch it back to ROS.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-26**:
I have updated the origin post,and I want to find out which portion I can focus.Thank you~

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-24**:
https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/rx/trunk/rxgraph/

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-24**:
If I want to see the source code of rxgraph,where is it? I trace 'rxgraph' only see import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('rxgraph');import rxgraph;rxgraph.rxgraph_main()